# What google image can I use in my site for "Login with google"

Tags: authentication, oauth, permissions, graphical-logo

I am building a web application and I need it to have facebook and google authentication, but I can't find information about the use of google's policies for brand image use for this case.

For facebook I found this:

https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

but I can't find a similar page for google's brand image, all I found was this:

http://www.google.com/+/business/brand-guidelines.html

but they don't talk about login.

Thank you very much in advace for your help

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365978/what-google-logo-can-i-use-on-my-site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the specific buttons and branding guidelines for sign-in buttons:
https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines

Comment: Can you update to the latest branding guidelines link? https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines